# Disable Wallet (Passbook) support for iOS app

Tags: ios, passbook, wallet

I enabled Passbook support for my app in previous versions. Now I want to disable it so that it is not listed in passbook-supported section in app store any longer. I have disabled wallet in app's capabilities in Xcode, disabled wallet in developer console, removed pass id, but the app store listing page sill states that my app supports wallet. What should I do?

Comment: Did you remove the entitlement from your app?

Comment: Yes, I removed the entitlement.

Comment: I encountered the same problem. Did you resolve this?

Comment: No, unfortunately not